# Obtaining perfect channel estimates in simulated channel estimation

Tags: channel-estimation

In SISO systems of OFDM, I am interested in applying deep learning for channel estimation, but I am unsure of how to obtain perfect channel estimation as the label in simulations. If you have any insights on obtaining perfect channel estimation in a simulation, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Thank you.